# LayoutTransition doesnt work on Adding view onActivityResult() method

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to achieve animation of shifting views to right when a new view is added.

I am using LayoutTransition Animation of LayoutTransition.APPEARING. Im adding new view at 0th position of linear layout.

It works fine except for the one case when the view gets added from onActivityResult().

When i start Activity for result and tries to add view in onActivityResult() method, view get added however LayoutTransition animation does work.

Scenario 1: Activity A starts Activity B for result. Activity B setResult() and finish() without doing anything. In this case LayoutTransition  animation works fine.

Scenario 2: Activity A starts Activity B for result. Activity B has Button. On Click of Button Activity B setResult() and finish(). In this case LayoutTransition  animation doesnt work.

Need inputs on where i'm going wrong or any workaround for achieving the animation.

Activity A

```
private LinearLayout ll;
private Button b, addbutton, setResultButton;
private LayoutTransition transitioner;
private Animator defaultAppearingAnim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);

ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    transitioner = new LayoutTransition();
    defaultAppearingAnim = transitioner
            .getAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
    transitioner.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING,
            defaultAppearingAnim);
    ll.setLayoutTransition(transitioner);

/*Adds Buttons to Linear Layout*/
    addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

/*Adds Buttons to Linear Layout on onActivityResult method*/
    setResultButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    setResultButton.setOnClickListener(this);


   /*Dummy Button Added here*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("B " + i);
        ll.addView(b);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Result from Activity B we are adding Button to LinearLayout
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("RT");
    ll.addView(b, 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == setResultButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } else if (v == addbutton) {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("T");
        ll.addView(b, 0);
    }
}
```

Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);

  /*   SCENARIO 1: LayoutTransition works if the activity setResult and finish
 setResult(0);  
 finish();  
   */

/* SCENARIO 2: Here the LayoutTransition animation doesnt work*/

    Button setResultButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    setResultButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setResult(0);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it Working

Solution for Scenario 2:

Here in this case i have added the view using post() method

```
ll.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button b = new Button(ActivityA.this);
    b.setText("RT");
    ll.addView(b, 0);
 }
});
```